# Loading assemblies at run-time

Tags: c#, .net

My project is an application in which we load various assemblies and perform operations on them.

We are stuck at a situation where we need to add a reference to the assembly we load (which will be selected by user). So I need to add a reference to the DLL at run time.

I tried [this site](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/addrefvsnet.aspx) but here they support only microsoft DLLs like System.Security etc.  I want to add a reference to a user created dll (class library).

Comment: For info, the code-project link is really about editing Visual Studio projects; not loading assemblies at runtime.

Comment: ya man i want to add reference to my current visual studio projects

Comment: But "visual studio projects" is the exact opposite of "at run-time". Please clarify your intent. Is the app running? Or are you in the Visual Studio designer editing code?

Comment: app is running i want to add it in references for eg u add a reference by right clicking in solution bar but i want to a similar operation when my appilication is running

Comment: Did you resolve the "null" issue?

Comment: Since now resolved (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649522/649539#649539), care to accept as answer?

Comment: In case google search for .NET core brings you here, you can check this library for .NET core+ versions: https://github.com/dheerajawale-svg/dynamic-dependency-loader.
It helped me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't "add a reference" at runtime - but you can load assemblies - `Assembly.LoadFrom` / `Assembly.LoadFile` etc. The problem is that you can't *unload* them unless you use `AppDomain`s. Once you have an `Assembly`, you can use `assemblyInstance.GetType(fullyQualifiedTypeName)` to create instances via reflection (which you can then cast to known interfaces etc).

For a trivial example:

```
// just a random dll I have locally...
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(@"d:\protobuf-net.dll");
Type type = asm.GetType("ProtoBuf.ProtoContractAttribute");
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

At which point I can either cast `instance` to a known base-type/interface, or continue to use reflection to manipulate it.

Comment: Then you haven't given it the correct fully-qualified name, or it doesn't exist; Assembly.GetType() will find even private types, etc. Note that generics and nested types get slightly different syntax to what you see in C#.

Comment: what is ProtoBu men here is it the dll name . i gave my dll name and the class which i require

Comment: Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Documents and Settings\E454930\Desktop\nunit_dll_hutt\for_hutt_proj\bin\Debug\for_hutt_proj.dll");
            Type type = asm.GetType("for_hutt_proj.int");
            object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
this is what i did what is mistake here

Answer (score 1):

If the assembly is in another location than the current or in the GAC, just use the
***AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve*** event to deliver the assembly yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you load an assembly at runtime, it will look for all its dependencies in the current location or the GAC, and load them if found, else error.

Answer (score 0):

The Composite UI Application Block facilitates the design and implementation of your client applications in three areas:

- It allows your application to be based on the concept of modules or plug-ins.
- It allows developers with shell expertise to build components that hide user interface complexity from the business logic development.
- It facilitates development using patterns for loose coupling between modules.

For WPF: Take a look at [Prism: patterns & practices Composite Application Guidance for WPF and Silverlight site](http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF)  It does the assembly loading you require and actually uses Unity internally as it's IoC container.

For non WPF: Take a look at [Smart Client - Composite UI Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480450.aspx)

Or alternatively: Try any of the IoC containers like [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/index.html), autofac, unity, etc.