# Type is returning null for a loaded assembly?

Tags: c#

```
//here assembly is loaded
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Documents and Settings\E454930\Desktop\nunit_dll_hutt\for_hutt_proj\bin\Debug\for_hutt_proj.dll");    
Type type = asm.GetType("for_hutt_proj.class1"); //returning null  
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

This is what I did, can anyone see what the mistake is here?

Here type is returning null. What is a fully qualified name
here for_hutt_proj is my dll name and class1 is my type name

Comment: I did my best to clean up the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine... the only things I wonder is whether the casing of the type-name is correct. You could try:

```
Type type = asm.GetType("for_hutt_proj.class1", false, true);
```

which will do a case-insensitive search.

Also; is `for_hutt_proj` a *namespace* or an *outer-class*? i.e. if it is:

```
class for_hutt_proj {
    class class1 {}
}
```

then this is `for_hutt_proj+class1` in terms of fully-qualified names. Namespaces remain as `.` - i.e.

```
namespace for_hutt_proj {
    class class1 {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems fine. Try posting more info, and use formatting.

Comment: i posted it because its returning null and its not fine so plz try to help

Comment: for_hutt_proj its also the namespace name

Answer (score 0):

In a test find out what an instance of this class prints for its type, such as:

```
for_hutt_proj.class1 testClass = new for_hutt_proj.class1();
Console.WriteLine(testClass.GetType().ToString());
```

Then use this string value in your asm.GetType method