# Can I use iframe kind of something in WPF application window

Tags: c#, wpf

i want to create and application that is having window that runs another .exe(Application for eg. Camera.exe) at half site and other control (My application on other side[image])

**Is it Possible in wpf? How Can i achieve this?**

Comment: If the other application contains a control for this purpose you can simply import that one.

Comment: It's is. Load in the dll of that application with reflection.

Comment: @RononDex : do you mean third party tools? .dll's?

Comment: @Djerry : can you please elaborate you comment. reflection??

Comment: Look at the answer Marc gave on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641961/loading-assemblies-at-run-time , if there's a possibility to get it to work, I think reflection is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the Windows API functions FindWindow and SetParent. The FindWindow retrieves a handle to the top-level window whose class name and window name match the specified strings, and SetParent function can change the parent window of the specified child window.

For more information about these two functions, please refer the links as follows:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499(VS.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633541(VS.85).aspx

Hope this helps.